# focusLost event apparently ignores loop

Tags: java

I am learning Java in a YouTube course and apparently ran into this problem. I tried to create a loop within focusLostevento. However, it does not work correctly (the program ignores it). If anyone has the solution, I will be happy to hear it.
I have tried several ways to do it but none works.
The task is to do two JTextField in the first text box write the email and when it loses focus using the loop go through all the text inside and check if it is a valid email looking for the @ but for some reason it does not enter the loop

```
package Ventanas;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    public  MainFrame() {
        setTitle("Primer JText en Java");
        setBounds(500,500,700,700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        add(mainPanel);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        setLayout(null);

        Square1 = new JTextField();
        Square2 = new JTextField();

        Square1.setBounds(120, 120 , 100, 25);
        Square2.setBounds(120, 160, 100, 25);

        add(Square1);
        add(Square2);

        focusEvent fEvent = new focusEvent();

        Square1.addFocusListener(fEvent);

    }

     class focusEvent implements FocusListener{


        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String mail = Square2.getText();

            boolean comprobacion = false;

            for (int i=0; i<mail.length();i++) {

                if (mail.charAt(i)=='@') {

                    comprobacion= true;
                }
            }


            if (comprobacion){
                System.out.println("El email es válido");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("El email no es válido");

            }

        }       

     }

     JTextField Square1;
     JTextField Square2;


}
public class WindowFocusListenerAndJText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The focus event is added to the first text field

```
Square1.addFocusListener(fEvent)
```

Then the email validation is for the second text field

```
String mail = Square2.getText(); // or change this to Square1.getText();
```

It will work if you add the email in the second text field and lose focus for the first text field

Comment: or instead of hardcoded accessing a component use the component of the `FocusEvent`: `String mail = arg0.getComponent().getText();` (naming like in original post)